# Extract Image Path From Html Tag

Tags: android, html

I Have Html String And I Want To Extract Only Image Path From It. Can Anyone Have Idea?

Here Is My Html String

```
'<p>Testing Android <img alt="" src="http://111.90.169.104/Testing/Images/Item/Prachi%202120160730161908694.jpeg" style="width: 960px; height: 614px;" /></p>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Regex** for this problem this code might work for you
.

- First Add your html into a string

  ```
  String html;
  ```
- Use this code

  ```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
  while(m.find()){
        //Displaying the url
        System.out.println(m.group(1));}
  ```

Comment: thnx bro you saved my day

Comment: @MayankWadhwa Excellent solution, but it's you're not your

Answer (score 1):

just pass your html responce to this method it will give you the image path

```
public String getImagePathFromHtml(String mYourHtmlString) {
        String mArray[] = mYourHtmlString.split(" ");
        for (String mString : mArray) {
            if (mString.contains("http://") || mString.contains("https://")) {
                mString= mString.replace("src=","");
                return mString.substring(1,mString.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```